# fill depending on the number of consecutive NAs

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyr

Here is the example dataframe:

```
df1 <- read.table(text = "DT   odczyt.1
'2023-08-16 06:57:15'   482.307
'2023-08-16 06:57:30'   482.307
'2023-08-16 06:57:45'   482.311
'2023-08-16 06:58:00'   NA
'2023-08-16 06:58:15'   NA
'2023-08-16 06:58:30'   482.315
'2023-08-16 06:58:45'   482.315
'2023-08-16 06:59:00'   482.318
'2023-08-16 06:59:15'   482.324
'2023-08-16 06:59:30'   NA
'2023-08-16 06:59:45'   NA
'2023-08-16 07:00:00'   NA
'2023-08-16 07:00:15'   NA
'2023-08-16 07:00:30'   NA
'2023-08-16 07:00:45'   NA", header = TRUE)
```

I want to complete the data, but only if NA occurs in a maximum of three consecutive rows. When there are more missing data, NA remains.

`tidyr::fill` runs continuously. Adding a condition for a group doesn't seem to be justified either (I found such an example [Fill NA with condition based on the same column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71916200/fill-na-with-condition-based-on-the-same-column)).

In addition, the last value in the column can be NA.

Instead of `fill`, I also consider `na.approx`. `na.approx` would be better, but I don't know if it's possible because of the NA in the last line

Expected result

```
df1 <- read.table(text = "DT   odczyt.1
'2023-08-16 06:57:15'   482.307
'2023-08-16 06:57:30'   482.307
'2023-08-16 06:57:45'   482.311
'2023-08-16 06:58:00'   482.311
'2023-08-16 06:58:15'   482.311
'2023-08-16 06:58:30'   482.315
'2023-08-16 06:58:45'   482.315
'2023-08-16 06:59:00'   482.318
'2023-08-16 06:59:15'   482.324
'2023-08-16 06:59:30'   NA
'2023-08-16 06:59:45'   NA
'2023-08-16 07:00:00'   NA
'2023-08-16 07:00:15'   NA
'2023-08-16 07:00:30'   NA
'2023-08-16 07:00:45'   NA", header = TRUE)
```

Comment: Deleted my comment as I realised `vctrs::vec_fill_missing()` didn't do exactly what I thought it did. Andre's solution looks appropriate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An approach that does `fill` first and then subsequently conditionally filters with `ifelse`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df1 %>% 
  mutate(new = odczyt.1) %>% 
  fill(new) %>% 
  mutate(grp = consecutive_id(odczyt.1)) %>% 
  mutate(odczyt.1 = ifelse(sum(is.na(odczyt.1)) <= 3 & is.na(odczyt.1), 
                      new, odczyt.1), .by = grp) %>% 
 select(-c(new, grp))
                    DT odczyt.1
1  2023-08-16 06:57:15  482.307
2  2023-08-16 06:57:30  482.307
3  2023-08-16 06:57:45  482.311
4  2023-08-16 06:58:00  482.311
5  2023-08-16 06:58:15  482.311
6  2023-08-16 06:58:30  482.315
7  2023-08-16 06:58:45  482.315
8  2023-08-16 06:59:00  482.318
9  2023-08-16 06:59:15  482.324
10 2023-08-16 06:59:30       NA
11 2023-08-16 06:59:45       NA
12 2023-08-16 07:00:00       NA
13 2023-08-16 07:00:15       NA
14 2023-08-16 07:00:30       NA
15 2023-08-16 07:00:45       NA
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. It works and gives the result as expected.
I developed something like this myself:

```df1 %>%
  mutate(score_approx = na.approx(odczyt.1, maxgap = 6, na.rm = FALSE)) %>%
  ungroup```

What do you think ?

Comment: @GrBa It's a good solution (using `maxgap` with `zoo::na.approx`) if you want to approximate values based on flanking values of the gap, but if you want a pure fill it does not deliver the correct result.

Answer (score 1):

`na.locf`, `na.locf0` and `na.approx` (and also `na.aggregate`, `na.trim`, `na.spline` and `na.StructTS`) all support a `maxgap` argument

```
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)

df1 %>% 
  mutate(ozczyt.2 = na.locf0(odczyt.1, maxgap = 3))

df1 %>%
  mutate(ozczyt.2 = na.approx(odczyt.1, maxgap = 3))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way with zoo:

```
pacman::p_load(tidyverse, zoo)

df1 |> 
  mutate(n.1 = ifelse(rollapply(odczyt.1, 4, \(x) !all(is.na(x)), fill = FALSE, align = "left") & is.na(odczyt.1),
                      rollapplyr(odczyt.1, 3, \(x) x |> na.omit() |> last(), fill = NA),
                      odczyt.1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution using Rcpp.

#### Rcpp Function

```r
library(Rcpp)
library(tidyverse)

cppFunction("NumericVector rcpp_roll_na_fill(NumericVector x, double fill_limit) {
  NumericVector out = Rcpp::clone(x);
  R_xlen_t size = out.size();
  bool first_non_na = false;
  bool first_na = false;
  bool is_na;
  bool prev_is_not_na = false;
  R_xlen_t fill_count = 0;
  double fill;
  for (R_xlen_t i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
    is_na = NumericVector::is_na(out[i]);
    if (!first_non_na && !is_na){
      first_non_na = true;
    }
    if (!first_na && is_na){
      first_na = true;
      fill_count = 0;
    }
    // Are we in new NA run?
    if (first_non_na && is_na && prev_is_not_na){
      // Uncomment the below to match vctrs fill limit
      // fill_count = 0;
      fill = out[i - 1];
    }
    // Should we fill this NA value?
    if (first_non_na && is_na && fill_count < fill_limit){
      out[i] = fill;
    }
    fill_count += 1;
    prev_is_not_na = !is_na;
  }
  return out;
}")
```

```
df1 %>%
  mutate(filled = rcpp_roll_na_fill(odczyt.1, fill_limit = 2))
#>                     DT odczyt.1  filled
#> 1  2023-08-16 06:57:15  482.307 482.307
#> 2  2023-08-16 06:57:30  482.307 482.307
#> 3  2023-08-16 06:57:45  482.311 482.311
#> 4  2023-08-16 06:58:00       NA 482.311
#> 5  2023-08-16 06:58:15       NA 482.311
#> 6  2023-08-16 06:58:30  482.315 482.315
#> 7  2023-08-16 06:58:45  482.315 482.315
#> 8  2023-08-16 06:59:00  482.318 482.318
#> 9  2023-08-16 06:59:15  482.324 482.324
#> 10 2023-08-16 06:59:30       NA      NA
#> 11 2023-08-16 06:59:45       NA      NA
#> 12 2023-08-16 07:00:00       NA      NA
#> 13 2023-08-16 07:00:15       NA      NA
#> 14 2023-08-16 07:00:30       NA      NA
#> 15 2023-08-16 07:00:45       NA      NA
```